# Prefix for a textfield won't work

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to add a $ sign to the beginning of a textfield. If the character count is 1 then the $ sign is not hidden but if the character count is zero, the $ sign is hidden and the placeholder text will show. I have the code but its not working. It won't show the $ sign. Can you please help me. Here is the code below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.Price.delegate = self



    didChangeText()
}

var amount: String {
    get {
        if self._amount.characters.count > 1 {
            return (self._amount as NSString).substring(from: 2)
        }
        return ""
    }
}

// MARK: - UITextField Observing


private var newVal: String = ""
private var _amount: String = ""

func didChangeText() {
    if ((Price.text?.characters.count)! > 2) {
        if Price.text?.range(of: "$ ") == nil {
            Price.text = newVal
        }
    }

    if ((Price.text?.characters.count)! == 1) && ((Price.text?.characters.count)! > newVal.characters.count) {
        Price.text = "$ " + Price.text!
    }
    if ((Price.text?.characters.count)! == 2) && ((Price.text?.characters.count)! < newVal.characters.count) {
        Price.text = ""
    }
    newVal = Price.text ?? ""
    _amount = newVal
}
```

Comment: it didn't fix it. Thats not what I was looking for. I'm trying to add a prefix to the textfield

Comment: Keep in mind that people in Europe, Japan, and other countries that don't use the `$` symbol for their currency are not going to be happy with your app. And not all countries but the currency symbol before the number, many put it after. Use a `NumberFormatter` setup for currency.

Comment: can you show me how I could do that

Comment: Please do some research. There are plenty of examples showing how to format currency values for a text field.

Comment: should I have a picker. What should I do to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
let priceField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 30.0))
let leftDollarSymbol = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 15.0, height: 30.0))
leftDollarSymbol.textAlignment = .center
leftDollarSymbol.text = "$"
priceField.leftView = leftDollarSymbol
```

Update leftDollarSymbol as per your need or set leftview nil